# "Error: Arguments array must have arguments." AppModule

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

When running ng serve with a successful compilation in my Angular app, I started getting the following error in the browser console.

```
AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR Error: Arguments array must have arguments.

at injectArgs (core.js:1412)

at core.js:1491

at _callFactory (core.js:8438)

at _createProviderInstance (core.js:8396)

at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8371)

at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get
(core.js:9064)

 at resolveDep (core.js:9429)

 at createClass (core.js:9309)

 at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:9186)

  at createViewNodes (core.js:10406)
```

This as far as I can tell from Main.ts `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));`

I have deleted the node modules folder and reinstalled and I'm having trouble with the lack of explanation the error gives. Plus, I'm somewhat new to Angular.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## EDIT

I ran `ng serve --aot` and got the following error

```
ERROR in : Error: Internal error: unknown identifier []
 at Object.importExpr$$1 [as importExpr] (C:\Users\kg\Documents\ang2\ad\UI\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:21731:27)
 at C:\Users\kg\Documents\ang2\ad\UI\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:9988:37
 at Array.map (<anonymous>)
 at InjectableCompiler.depsArray (C:\Users\kg\Documents\ang2\ad\UI\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:9954:25)
 at InjectableCompiler.factoryFor (C:\Users\kg\Documents\ang2\ad\UI\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:10018:36)
 at InjectableCompiler.injectableDef (C:\Users\kg\Documents\ang2\ad\UI\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:10037:42)
 at InjectableCompiler.compile (C:\Users\kg\Documents\ang2\ad\UI\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:10047:106)
 at C:\Users\kg\Documents\ang2\ad\UI\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:21576:90
 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
 at AotCompiler._emitPartialModule2 (C:\Users\kg\Documents\ang2\ad\UI\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:21576:25)
 at C:\Users\kg\Documents\ang2\ad\UI\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:21569:48
 at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
 at AotCompiler.emitAllPartialModules2 (C:\Users\kg\Documents\ang2\ad\UI\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:21568:26)
 at AngularCompilerProgram._emitRender2 (C:\Users\kg\Documents\ang2\ad\UI\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:364:31)
 at AngularCompilerProgram.emit (C:\Users\kg\Documents\ang2\ad\UI\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:236:22)
 at AngularCompilerPlugin._emit (C:\Users\kg\Documents\ang2\ad\UI\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:846:49)
```

### ngModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ItemDashboardComponent,
    UnprotectedSearchComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    UnprotectedResultsComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    TrackingListComponent,
    ListItemComponent,
    ActionItemComponent,
    ActionListComponent,
    ItemInfoTableComponent,
    TrackingInfoTableComponent,
    FilterPipe,
    RegisterItemsComponent,
    RegisterPackageComponent,
    AddItemsPackageComponent,
    ChangeCustodyComponent,
    CheckTempComponent,
    RemoveItemsComponent,
    ScannerComponent,
    ContainerDashboardComponent,
    SoldComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    NgQrScannerModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    AngularFontAwesomeModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    BrowserModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    AngularFontAwesomeModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent
      },
      //{path: 'openSearch', component: LoginComponent},
      {
        path: 'item',
        component: ItemDashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard, ManufacturerAuthGuardService]
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'unprotectedResults',
        component: UnprotectedResultsComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'trackingList/'+environment.config.itemWorkflow+'/:contractId',
        component: ItemDashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'trackingList/'+environment.config.packageWorkflow+'/:contractId',
        component: ContainerDashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'trackingList',
        component: TrackingListComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'actions',
        component: ActionListComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'publicResults/:contractId',
        component: UnprotectedResultsComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'registerItems',
        component: RegisterItemsComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'addItemsToPackage',
        component: AddItemsPackageComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'registerPackage',
        component: RegisterPackageComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'changeCustody/:contractId',
        component: ChangeCustodyComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'changeCustody',
        component: ChangeCustodyComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'checkTemp',
        component: CheckTempComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'removeItems',
        component: RemoveItemsComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'sellItems',
        component: SoldComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },


    ]),
    UiModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthGuard,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MyInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    MockBackend,
    fakeBackendProvider,
    BaseRequestOptions,
    AuthGuard,
    AdminAuthGuard,
    AdalService,
    SoldComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

### AppComponent Constructor

```
constructor(private api: ApiService, private adalService: AdalService, private _http: HttpClient, private router: Router, public authService: AuthService) {
    this.adalService.init(environment.config);
    if (!this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated) this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, try building/serving the app with `ng serve --aot` flag. Chances are some warning/error will be shown at the compile time.

As far as I can think, can you search in your project, if you are importing any component/module

like this `import {something} from "../node_modules/@somepackage/adfas";` instead of `import {something} from "@somepackage/adfas";`

---

Also can you please share what you have in `@NgModule({})` decorator, and in `AppComponent constructor()`;

I think the angular is not able to provide all the injected dependencies.

Comment: `ApiService` service is not added in the providers. Can you please verify if you added in providers array?

Comment: also share imports which you have added in the top of the files

Comment: Adding ApiService into the providers helped expose the root cause ` Can't resolve all parameters for ApiService:`. It began to work normally when I removed the bad parameter. Thank you!

Comment: Some extra info, always use `--aot` or `--prod` flag get some help from the compiler, believe me sometimes this is the only saviour

Comment: @VivekKumar Thanks!  This saved me a ton!

Comment: @kg123 Thanks for sharing your comment about how it helped you expose the bad parameter.  I eventually figured out what you meant and removed my bad parameter.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same error because of a circular dependency in my code:

```
Service1 > Service2 > Service1
```

Answer (score 6):

i had the same issue, just tried to start app again and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was missing the injected **type** in the constructor :/

Answer (score 2):

This Typescript snippet demonstrates a scenario which causes this error.

```
...

export class AClassImportingAService {

    constructor(private _importedService) {
        // ERROR: notice there is no type on _importedService
        //   It should read 'private _importedService: ImportedService'
    }

...
}
```

Comment: Service with any type will cause this error as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had same error, when @Injectable decorator and export keyword were not used for a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error due to having a circular dependency. I had a store which depended on some initial state which was provided by a service that depended on my store.

I resolved the issue by extracting the initial state, which was a constant object, to its own constants file.

Answer (score 0):

I made a typo instead of ":" I used "," in the constructor and had this error:

```
constructor(private myService, Myservice) {
}

//instead of

constructor(private myService: Myservice) {
}
```