# Angular: Arguments array must have arguments

Tags: angular, typescript

I'am using a component in other component which looks like this:

```
<app-dialog-layout>
  <app-employee-create-edit (saveEmployee)="saveEmployee($event)"></app-employee-create-edit>
</app-dialog-layout>
```

In the `employee-create-edit` component I use the following inputs and outputs:

```
  @Input() isModal = false;
  @Input() set setEmployee(value: EmployeeInterface) {
    this.employee = value;
    this.isModal = true;
    this.employee.listingRulesRefresh();
  }
  @Input() companies: CompanyInterface[] = [];
  @Input() users: UserInterface[] = [];
  @Output() saveEmployee: EventEmitter<EmployeeInterface> = new EventEmitter();
```

The problem is that when I use the `employee-create-edit` component in other component I get the following error:

```
Error: Arguments array must have arguments.
    at injectArgs (core.js:685)
    at core.js:11183
    at _callFactory (core.js:20296)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:20254)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:20229)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:20905)
    at resolveDep (core.js:21276)
    at createClass (core.js:21156)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:21027)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:29387)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:852)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
    at zone.js:913
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:26247)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
```

When I comment this `employee-create-edit` component, the error is gone.
What is the couse of the problem? How could I solve it?

Comment: Could you try `@Output() saveEmployee: EventEmitter<EmployeeInterface> = new EventEmitter<EmployeeInterface>();` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but the error is same. :/

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52767225/error-arguments-array-must-have-arguments-appmodule) help ?

Comment: Have you tried this `@Input() companies: Array<CompanyInterface>;
  @Input() users: Array<UserInterface>;`

Comment: No, but i tried it now and the error is still same.

Comment: Try to comment each array you got to know which one is doing the error ( if you haven't done it before of course ) and try to not add a value to your array (  from `@Input() companies: CompanyInterface[] = [];` to `@Input() companies: CompanyInterface[];` )

Comment: Comment out every input and uncomment each and keep doing tests to track which Input is causing the error

Comment: I disabled all inputs and outputs in the components, and the error is still same. :/

Comment: It would be helpful if you could put together a stackblitz or something that demonstrates the issue. Here's a simple one I put together that shows nested components working correctly: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j6efrx. Maybe you can use that as a starting point? If that's not possible, it would help if you could show how you have your modules configured.

Comment: Also, are you intentionally using content projection here? dialog-layout's template includes an <ng-content> where employee-create-edit will be projected? Because if you just want employee-create-edit to be a child of dialog-layout, <app-employee-create-edit> should be in dialog-layout's template, not between its tags like you currently have it set up.

Comment: Check if you have any circular dependency in your code. For example: component1 -> component2 -> component1. Or between services.

Comment: check all your imports if imported inside employee-create-edit component.
ex. @Input(), or any class connected to your component.