# Angular, created a custom pipe that returns a function within a class. Keeps erroring

Tags: html, angular, pipe

I have a created class that returns a function inside of my model.ts folder, like so:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class Lookup {
  val: object,
  etc,
  etc,

  getLookupVal(field: string, id: number): string {
    returns stuff..
  }
}
```

This is what my custom pipe looks like:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Lookup } from '../config/models';

@Pipe({
  name: 'lookup'
})

export class LookupValuePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private _lookupValues: Lookup) { }
  transform(field: string, id: number): any {
    return this._lookupValues.getLookupVal(field, id);
  }
}
```

and here is an example of where I am using it:

```
<h3>{{'prodstands'| lookup: selectedTask.taskinfo.prodstandid}}</h3>

But for some reason this is the error I keep getting:
ERROR Error: Arguments array must have arguments.
at injectArgs (core.js:685)
at core.js:11183
at _callFactory (core.js:20296)
```

Comment: transform(field: string, id: number): any {
        return this._lookupValues.getLookupVal(field, id);
    }

What are the _lookupValues?

Comment: @RafaelAndrade sorry, I'm confused by your question

Comment: I think I understood now. 1 sec

Comment: everything looks ok from what i can tell by the code you posted. maybe you have a circular dependency somewhere. looks like angular has hard time injecting your dependency

Answer (score 0):

I did a example here to concat two strings and works fine.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jl6buq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Maybe there is something you are doing wrong - Check this thread ["Error: Arguments array must have arguments." AppModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52767225/error-arguments-array-must-have-arguments-appmodule)